# VBA - checkbox based on form

Tags: excel, vba

i'm pretty new at this so please be patient.

I have the following issue that i can't solve.

I have 2 Macro, Macro A and MACRO B.

Macro A is in an excel file in the form of a button that you press and it pops up a FORM for different currency. After the user selected the currency the macro opens up excel files in a specific location and runs macro B

Macro B is a more complex one that does a lot of things in the background and at some point opens a FORM and this one requires the user's input (selecting a currency)

What i am trying to do is in Macro A to select the Currency and automatically take this and apply it to the form in MACRO B for each file.

As Macro B is to complex for me i'd rather not modify anything in it as to not disrupt the normal procedure. Macro B needs to run the same if the user does not use the MACRO A.

Hope this was sufficient info for an idea on what to do.

What i have tried so far was with Initialize but my value is not getting stored. Seems a bit to complex so i'm looking for something a bit more easy. does not have to be clean or anything ..it should just work.

Comment: You aren't going to be able to get Macro B to use a value from Macro A without some modification to Macro B. I suggest looking at parameters.

Comment: In order to receive some help, it would be good to edit your question and instead a lot of works, please post the two macros code. In principle, you can send a parameter to the second macro...

Comment: If the two macros are in different workbooks then you need to somehow write the currency somewhere from macro A, and then read from that place in macro B. Whether that place is a text file, another workbook, some cell in a hidden worksheet somewhere both macros can access, ...by the sound of it you are looking at two "god-procedure" scripts - maybe a global variable could be "good enough", but we can't guess without seeing any of your code.

Comment: Have you tried to put the value (which the user selected in Macro A) in a sheet ? (say in cell AAA1). Then use this cell AAA1 as a reference for Macro B ? So in Macro B you need to check whether cell AAA1 has value or not. If no value, Macro B runs as usual, if cell AAA1 has value, Macro B runs based on that cell AAA1 value as a reference.

Comment: solved it by adding macro A to the procedure where Macro B is located and changed the automatic currency it would get by the normal procedure to  my string variable . so small modification to Macro B. the only slight difference this did is that when normally running the macro it does not select the currency by it self. but this is not an issue as the currency should always be checked by the user in the normal processes. EDIT : all suggestions were good

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can call MacroB with or without a provided currency

```
Sub MacroB(Optional curr As String = "")
    '...
    '...
    If Len(curr) = "" Then
        'not passed: get currency from user
    End If

    '...use currency

End Sub
```

The code in MacroA gets the currency from the user and calls:

```
MacroB myCurrency
```